# What kind of isomers are ethyl butanoate and propyl propanoate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, isomers, esters

Are ethyl butanoate (**1**) and propyl propanoate (**2**) metamers or functional group isomers? My book claims they are metamers, but here one group is $\ce{-CO-OR}$ and another is $\ce{-CO-OR'}$ where $\ce{R}$ is $2$ carbon and $\ce{R'}$ is $3$ carbon. Though both of them are esters, aren't the functional groups different?

[image: 1: ethyl butanoate; 2: propyl propanoate]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78783/what-is-metamerism?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Metamerism occurs when isomers have different alkyl chains on the sides of the functional groups. In the case of an ester, the relevant functional group is the ester (..O-C=O..) group. The length of R and R' has no bearing on the functional group in this case. An example of a functional isomer would be something like ethyl butanoate and caproic acid.